# View image from file in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

In one procedure I correctly create a bmp file called tempimage.bmp. I see the file in the folder, all right.
I would like to see this image in a control of the type System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image, called Image1.
I tried it like this:

```
string cPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\";
Image1.ImageUrl = cPath + "tempimage.bmp";
```

I don't get any errors but I don't see anything. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What URL does it generate when you view the image tag in the HTML?

Comment: <img id="Image1" src="D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb\tempimage.bmp" /> and is correct.

Comment: No, that's not correct. Think about how the web works. Do you think that a website can refer to a local path on your machine like `D:\`? No. Server.MapPath is for creating a local file system path - why are you using that to generate a URL for an image?

Comment: You're right, I changed the path, but now it no longer creates the bmp file and gives me this error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Generic error in GDI +.
At this line: bitmap.Save ("/ Images / tempimage.bmp");
I have checked the folder permissions and they look ok

Comment: I have also tried in other folders, including root, same error.

Comment: Why did you change how you're saving the file? When you're saving the file, you need to pick a location on the server side, thus Server.MapPath is appropriate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb\ is your root directory

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "/tempimage.bmp";
```

If it can change do

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/tempimage.bmp");
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks, unfortunately I've always created WinForms applications, with Asp.net I'm just a fool.

Comment: It all depends on your needs but generally speaking when you set up `src="D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb\tempimage.bmp"` this path will exist and might work (or might not, due to permissions of current identity) only on your box. Any remote user of your app will not see this path i.e. this is why all the links are assumed to start from the root folder (domain name) of the site. `/` stands for the root of the site,  `~/` stands for the root of current application (complex sites could have multiple sub-applications below root folder).

Comment: I don't understand, everything is fine on my computer, if I publish on my IIS server I get this error:
bitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + "Immagini/tempimage.bmp");
In Html i read: 
Sicaweb._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\DOTNET2019\Sicaweb\Default.aspx.cs:31
But the path: D: \ DOTNET2019 \ Sicaweb \ doesn't exist on my server, but only on my computer. Where do you get it from? I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only the automatic publication of Visual Studio which clears the folder permissions every time.